# How would one get the HTML structure of a web page as a numeric vector?

Tags: clustering, web-scraping

Suppose you want to cluster, or classify, web pages inside a domain.
In the same domain similar web pages always have the same structure more or less. (think of every product page an e-commerce would have)

My idea is to convert the HTML tags of every page to a numeric vector, then use those with the clustering method of your choice.
In this contest we would not need the actual content of the page, just the structure.

**But how to do that?**

The first idea I got was to assign every tag a position (sequential), a depth (how inside of other tags it is), and an ID that would identify which kind of tag it is (< img >, < h1 >, < div >...)

Comment: Well, this step is the one where you need a good idea then... Turning data into a vector and then magically solving everything is not really an "idea", you know. I have major doubt it will be sufficient to only look at the structure; because the HTML structure is known to change, even when the page contents remain the same...

Comment: If a web page structure is going to change, every page of the same type most of the times will have the same changes. Especially for websites created with a CMS or something similar

Comment: So everything will have the same vector, sounds useless to me?

Comment: But the goal is to cluster together pages with different urls but the same html structure

Comment: Well, if all you care is the structure, then just go ahead and define structural features, then cluster them. But if they are that similar and come from a CMS, I am fairly certain there is an easier way to do this. Such as product identifiers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure a vector is the best way to represent a web page. Given the tree structure, you love valuable information if you "transform" if into a vector. Given how different one web page can be to another, you might end up with a very large dimension feature vector.

Maybe graphs are better suited to your problem?